# Deprecated warnings, how to find replacement code in the help fast

Tags: ios, xcode

I find sometime deprecated warnings in my code, it shows the deprecated method name in the Issue Navigator, is there any shortcut or command to jump into the docs at the replacement method I could use to remove that old method fast ?

I would like to avoid jumping around the docs and searching manually for every deprecated method the compiler finds.

What's your best practice you use to do that fast without loosing concentration by having to search manually.

Using Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: A simple web search would help. Most of the deprecated methods or properties are already asked and answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try option-clicking over the method, and choose the class reference at the bottom of the popover that comes up. It should take you to the depreciated method, which usually informs you of the method that replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Inspector sidebar. Select the depreciated method and it will show under the Quick Help tab.

Comment: Your answer is correct too, but option-clicking is more usable and the popup panel is has better layout, and doesn't require having quick help always visible.